# Can't download the whole set of reviews from Steam

Tags: python, extract, text-mining, steam

I would like to use some machine learning classification on games reviews. First thing to do is retrieving the reviews.
In order to do this, I am using the code from [here](https://andrew-muller.medium.com/scraping-steam-user-reviews-9a43f9e38c92) to download reviews from Steam. In particular I would like to retrieve the reviews:

1. from [this game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1794680/Vampire_Survivors/) (app ID 1794680)
2. only English reviews
3. sorted from the most recent ones

This is the code that I modified from the source:

```
import requests

def get_reviews(appid, params={'json':1}):
        url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/'
        response = requests.get(url=url+appid, params=params, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        return response.json()
    
def get_n_reviews(appid, n):
    reviews = []
    cursor = '*'
    params = {
            'json' : 1,
            'filter' : 'recent',
            'language' : 'english',
            'day_range' : 9223372036854775807,
            'review_type' : 'all',
            'purchase_type' : 'all'
            }

    while n > 0:
        params['cursor'] = cursor.encode()
        params['num_per_page'] = 100
        n -= 100

        response = get_reviews(str(appid), params)
        cursor = response['cursor']
        reviews += response['reviews']

        if len(response['reviews']) < 100: break

    return reviews

n=26731
response_3=get_n_reviews(1794680,n)
```

My issue: from what I see from the website there should be 26,731 reviews to be retrieved using my parameters. However, I am able to retrieve only 12600.

Why?

Lastly, this is only my curiosity: what is *9223372036854775807* number used to download every reviews from day zero?

Comment: That number is [two to the power of 63](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#2^63) which as the link says is `"The number of non-negative values for a signed 64-bit integer"`

Comment: @HampusLarsson so is it used to have a very big number to be sure to include any possible review in the system?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only gets reviews in English, try removing the language parameter altogther.

Comment: I need the English reviews and they are more than the one I got it seems

Answer (score 0):

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews
I found that Steam API will filter off-topic reviews (aka "Review Bombs") by default, which may probably be the reason why the reviews are not the whole set.